# WP_User_Query users by registered date

Tags: wp-user-query

I'm trying to get the number of user who registered today.

I've tried this:

```
$args = array (
'role'           => 'Subscriber',
'meta_query'     => array(
    array(
        'key'       => 'user_registered',
        'value'     => '2015-01-13 00:00:00',
        'compare'   => '>=',
        'type'      => 'DATE', //also tried DATETIME, TIME
    ),
 ),
);

$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
$user_query->total_users;
```

But the results is always 0.

This works:

```
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM `wp_users` WHERE `user_registered` >= '2015-01-13 00:00:00'");
echo count($results);
```

But shouldn't WP_User_Query() be able to do this. Am I doing something wrong with the args?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply use the `date_query` parameter on the user registration date:

```
$args = array (
    'role'          => 'subscriber',
    'date_query'    => array(
        array(
            'after'     => '2010-01-13 00:00:00',
            'inclusive' => true,
        ),
     ),
);

$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
```

[This part](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1/src/wp-includes/user.php#L767) of the `WP_User_Query` source code, makes it possible:

```
// Date queries are allowed for the user_registered field.
if ( ! empty( $qv['date_query'] ) && is_array( $qv['date_query'] ) ) {
    $date_query = new WP_Date_Query( $qv['date_query'], 'user_registered' );
    $this->query_where .= $date_query->get_sql();
}
```

Comment: what does ```'inclusive' => true,``` do in this query?

Comment: From docs: *inclusive (boolean) – For after/before, whether exact value should be matched or not’.*